# Top 10 in a stream of key value pairs in the last one hour

Tags: algorithm, live

Lets say there is a stream of key value pairs with a timestamp and we would like to find top 10 keys with highest value in the last one hour. ( The value of key in the last one hour is sum of all values streamed of that particular key).

I tried and came up with a solution that looks like : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-stream-of-integers-running-integers/ . But I am unable to bring time into picture without costing me heavy on time complexity. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you need an exact answer, or will an approximate one do?  Also do you need an online algorithm (you always have the top 10 available), or would offline batch processing (eg a map-reduce) suffice?

Comment: I prefer exact one, but even approximate should be ok. But I was asked this an interview question and they require a online algorithm. Actually I used heaps and hashmaps, but he is not satisfied the space and time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an exact online algorithm, you're going to need multiple copies of everything.  You need to keep track of by value, the keys in a sorted data structure like a red-black tree.  You need to keep track of by key, the value in any quick key lookup - a hash will work.  And you need some sort of event-loop/queue of observations so that you can remove stuff that is over an hour old.

With that, your process for adding an observation looks like:

1. Remove any observations that are currently to remove.  (More on how to do that in a minute.)
2. Add the observation to the queue for to-delete, with the timestamp to delete it.
3. By the key, find the current total value in the hash of value by key.
4. By the value+key, find the entry in the balanced binary tree, and remove it.
5. Update the current total value in the hash of value by key.
6. Insert the new value in the hash of value by key.

To find the top 10, you need to follow a similar path.

1. Remove any observations that are currently to remove.  (More on how to do that in a minute.)
2. Look in the balanced binary tree for the top 10 observations.

And to remove observations that are currently to remove, while the top element in the to remove queue is more than one hour old:

1. Pop a key/value pair from the to remove queue.
2. Find the value in the hash of total value by key.
3. Remove the value from the balanced binary tree.
4. Update the total value in the hash of total value by key.
5. Insert the new value/key into the balanced binary key.

OK, so what are the costs and the time?

We keep 3 copies of every observation.  Some in complex data structures with overhead.  So we're using perhaps 5x the space for the last hour's events.  There are a lot of operations per observation, but they are all logarithmic.  In fact the total effort per observation scales like `O(log(n))` both for keeping the data structure up to date, and for returning the top 10.

Now if overhead becomes too much, the simple solution is to make it approximate.  There are a ton of approximation algorithms, but the easiest thing to do is to make inclusion in the data structure be random. For example you can say that anything with value above 100 gets included at 1% of its value, and anything with value below has its value as its percentage chance of being included.  Then multiply final answers by 100.  If average value is in the 1-10 range, then a `O(1)` filter just removed `90-99%` of the needed data storage and work.  But you'll have approximate answers that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks ! The idea behind approximation is more awesome.